# how to prove heptagon that don't have a perfect matching using tutte's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

From wikipedia, a graph, G = (V, E), has a perfect matching if and only if for every subset U of V, the subgraph induced by V − U has at most |U| connected components with an odd number of vertices.

I do know heptagon doesn't have a perfect matching but how to find a vertex set U such that V − U has more than |U| connected components with an odd number of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether your heptagon is $K_7$ or a $7$-cycle, but in either case you can take $ U = {\varnothing}
 $ ...

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice U can be empty set.....

Comment: @PayC.: One needs to allow empty $U$; otherwise Tutte would wrongly conclude that every complete graph has a perfect matching.